# Procedural generation of terrain/waves based strictly on perlin noise?

Tags: procedural, ocean-simulation

So basically I'm trying to make some waves (like an ocean) based strictly on perlin noise where I can control the seed and scalar and stuff. It has to be exact because my goal is to export it into a game engine and be able to calculate the wave size based on the perlin noise of the X and Y of the position I want to calculate.

Does anyone know if you can do this in blender natively, or if there's a script for it? I'm unfamiliar with blender btw.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried creating a subdivided plane, adding a displacement modifier, and then setting the texture to Perlin Noise?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32844/how-to-procedurally-generate-an-infinite-terrain-using-perlin-noise?r=SearchResults&s=2|40.6140

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to procedurally generate an infinite terrain using perlin noise](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32844/how-to-procedurally-generate-an-infinite-terrain-using-perlin-noise)

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. @person132 that's actually really interesting, I never thought of using a bitmap for perlin noise, although now that I look into it, it seems to be very popular. I'll look into it more. Thank you!